# Is 'getting more used to' bad use of english?

Tags: grammar, expressions

Is it correct to say 'She is getting more used to me visiting'? I am just wondering about the use of 'more'.

Comment: It's the use of 'get' that people would probably take more issue with. 'Get' implies something more active than what you are trying to convey. As a preference I would use "She is becoming more used to me visiting.' Out of interest, what did you think was wrong with using 'more?'

Comment: @Jascol: Are you seriously suggesting that most native speakers would prefer [*I'm **becoming** used to it*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%27m+becoming+used+to+it%22) over [*I'm **getting** used to it*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%27m+getting+used+to+it%22) ?!?. According to those Google Books searches, the former is almost 400 times less common.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: in the U.S., there are certain misguided grammar police who think *"get"* is colloquial, and should be avoided whenever possible. I suspect that this started with the use of *got* or *have got* for *have* and was mistakenly broadened to cover all uses of *get*.

Comment: @Peter: I understand that - in fact I'd say there's more than a *soupcon* of the same prejudice on this side of the pond (but I bet at least some of *our* grammar nazis take issue with it purely on the grounds that it's *American!* :) Personally I've no problem with most uses of ***get***, but I can never remember how you guys decide when it's "okay" to use ***gotten*** (or how strictly observed the rule is), so I probly get that one "wrong" quite often. But grammar nazis are wasting their time railing against actual usage figures showing a 400:1 preference for a usage they object to.

Comment: (btw - is *grammar **nazi*** acceptable in AmE, or is that another "N-word"?)

Comment: @Peter: I just read a fascinating article last night by Prof Andy Clark at Edinburgh University on [*Language As An Adaptive System: Humans As Hosts*](http://www.research.ed.ac.uk/portal/en/publications/the-iterated-learning-explanation-of-structured-language-language-as-an-adaptive-system-humans-as-hosts(48d69d32-6e61-4289-a48f-bfd79e37b2be).html). I suppose from *that* perspective, grammar nazis are effectively "antibodies". But I have every confidence the English language will continue to evolve and thrive, their efforts notwithstanding.

Comment: @FumbleFingers; I'm suggesting that some people might take umbrage at the use of 'get.' I don't 'get' it myself, but still. It's the same as with splitting the infinitive: it's fine to do, most people either don't care or wouldn't recognise a split infinitive if it were to hit them in the face. Those that do care though, really seem to care.

Comment: Aren't you guys supposed to be busy asking the OP to put a reference/research in the question and closing it? I see only one close vote cast. What is X Nazi to do with the question? I will flag all of your irrelevant comments and see what happens.

Comment: @Jascol: oic. Well, it seems OP is really asking whether such pedants are unwilling to *get **more** strident* in their opposition to whatever it is they don't like (which may fact that they don't like ***get*** in general, or perhaps they just don't like it conjoined with ***more***).

Comment: @Rathony: I have already voted to close on the grounds that OP hasn't provided any evidence to suggest *anyone* could object to ***more*** in such constructions. Given there are several thousand written instances of [*getting more used to (something)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22getting+more+used+to%22) in Google Books, it's not obvious to me why this question should even arise in the first place, regardless of whether the focus is on ***get, more,*** or ***used to***, or some specific combination of those elements.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Let me be blunt with you, please. Why do you think others (especially who downvoted my question and flagged my question) don't share your opinion? There is no reference/research in this question and this question is so basic that it might not be able to survive in ELL. It is very obvious that there are double standards and as I concluded in my previous question posted, "Applying double standards is worse than never having any standard."

Comment: @Rathony [Let us continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30917/double-standards)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am in the room. You don't seem to respond. I will leave the room unless there is any response from you in a few minutes.

Comment: @Jascol: Shakespeare used *get*, Jane Austen used *get*, F. Scott Fitzgerald used *get*, Ernest Hemingway used *get*, and Henry James used *get*. I would bet there is not one well-respected writer in the English language who has not used *get*. The advice *"don't use get"* should be ignored.

Comment: It is correct as written, though clearly there are various ways to reword it.

Comment: @Peter - like I clarified: I do t necessarily agree with the advice, but some style guides/ over-zealous grammarians see it as bad practice. So no, it should not necessarily be ignored. Also, it's not about not using 'get.' It's about using it in that specific context.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct, just not very nice to the ear. I'd say the "more" can just be dropped as it is slightly redundant.

> She is getting used to me visiting

"Getting" already implies an action over time. Hence the "more" isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: I disagree. _More_ does add something to the meaning.

Comment: I'm with @ColinFine. "getting used to" suggests that the process of becoming comfortable is mostly complete. "getting more used to" implies that her comfort is slowly increasing, but is not close to completed yet.